# Visual Studio Code: C++ Compiling Argument -o

Tags: c++, g++, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to grab the filename of what you will compile in Visual Studio Code?

Ex.
I have "asdf.cpp", and I want it to automatically have an output executable of name "asdf.exe" or something.

For this purpose, anytime that I would compile, I wouldn't have to go and modify the "tasks.json" file, and so that my programs have their .cpp files and their respective .exe files by their side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using CMake Tools vscode extension and a simple CMakeLists.txt file consisting of:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (Try)
add_executable(Main main.cpp)
```

You can learn more about cmake here https://cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/, but with the extension that integrates it, these three lines are enough for you to make and build program with vscode commands and get executable "Main" in /build folder that will be created inside working directory.